# SELECT statement with * and ( + )

Tags: sql, select

What does this select statement mean with `*` and `(column_name1 + column_name2)`?

I don't understand it when they have `*` and `()`.

```
SELECT 
    ProductName, 
    UnitPrice * (UnitsInStock + COALESCE(UnitsOnOrder, 0))
FROM 
    Products;
```

Just for a question, didn't try anything.

Comment: * multiplies, braces are required to prevent that the standard "point before line" rule will be applied. COALESCE replaces NULL values with another value, here 0.

Comment: It's just a mathematical formula to compute the product of `UnitPrice` and (`UnitsInStock + UnitsOnOrder)`

Answer (score 2):

Your SQL statement basically says that select two columns from Products which is `ProductName` and a `calculated field`, the `UnitPrice * (UnitsInStock + COALESCE(UnitsOnOrder, 0))`.

To simply put:

First, the COALESCE returns the non-NULL value. In this case, it will return 0 if the value of the "UnitsOnOrder" column is NULL, just like @Jonas Metzler says. Second, the "UnitsInStock" column value is added to the result of the COALESCE. Finally, the result from the second step is multiplied by "UnitPrice", which gives the total value of the product.